# Cut a cube into 5 objects

Tags: geometry, three-dimensional

Cut a cube into 5 3D objects with 6 edges each.

Hint:

> (I assume there is only one solution): only 4 of the objects are pyramids, ie tetrahedrons with one vertex containing only right angles

Comment: Are you sure there is no error in your question? 4 with 4 edges and 4 as pyramids out of 5 objects implies at least 3 pyramids with 4 edges. Under the usual definitions of which I'm aware there's no such thing. Should this have an enigmatic tag or something?

Comment: Did you mean faces maybe?

Comment: @Dr Xorile Yes, as it is presented I have a drawing of this. I may tell you that this is a result (hint?) of unfolding of a certain 4D right angle pyramid and rearranging the components of its "surface" (volume!)

Comment: @athin I meant 5 3D objects.

Comment: @Dr it is clear that you have 4 pyramids - 4 edges implies a pyramid. The additional infor mation of 4 pyramid shows that the 5th object is not a pyramid.

Comment: @Moti: Triangular pyramids have 4 faces, 4 corners, but 6 edges. A polyhedron with 4 edges does not exist.

Comment: @Japp YOU ARE RIGHT. My mistake and I edited the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @Dr Xoorile and athin I made an error by stating 4 edges for the 4 pyramids, it should 6 edges for all 5 objects of which 4 are pyramids. Edited accordingly the question. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Will post the answer in 3 days.

Comment: @Moti ok so... all $5$ objects are having $6$ edges, but only $4$ of them are pyramids, right?

Comment: Also, the only polyhedron with 6 edges is a tetrahedron (not necessarily regular of course). Dr Xorile's answer is the obvious one where you have 4 equal tetrahedra (pyramids) and one central regular tetrahedron.

Comment: The accepted answer has five pyramids, not just four. One of these pyramids is a regular tetrahedron and the other four are not, but all five are pyramids. (In the geometry sense of the word)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Draw a diagonal line on one of the faces and the orthogonal line on the opposite face. Join the ends of those lines together. With those as the cut points you get four corners of the cube (each with 4 sides) and the remainder is a tetrahedron with 6 edges.

The above is now correct given the update made by the OP.

Here's a rendering of the dissection done in TinkerCad:

> [image: Cube Dissection]

This is a link to the Tinkercad object:

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/7cW3ibU52v3

If you go there you should be able to spin it around and stuff.

Comment: It is OK. At least you caught it:) I had to be accurate in describing the requirements so a simple cut into 5 slices will not be a solution - this is the purpose of the edges definition.

Comment: The question has been edited to say 6 edges for all objects so I think this solution is valid now.

Comment: I like the answer, but there was a lot of confusion by OP in the question terminology. Rot13(Jul vfa'g n erthyne grgenurqeba pbafvqrerq gb or n clenzvq?)

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that OP is uses the word "pyramid" to refer to a right-angled tetrahedron.  This seemed to be the case on a previous question of theirs which I answered. I don't think there exists a 3d shape with 6 edges which is not a tetrahedron.

Comment: @hexomino that's true, but a regular tetrahedron is a special case of the [pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)), where any of its faces can be the pyramid's base.